# Java objects and references: Why would this work; mainApp.getProductsData().remove(selectedItem)

Tags: java

I am quite new to Java. I have seen a lot of this in Java code from other developers and I am not so sure whether Java keeps track of every single object it creates. Suppose I was working in JavaScript and I wrote something like this;

```
//I could not do the following in JavaScript
var myProduct = new Product("Product name", "SKU", "20", "20.93", "12.5");
productCollection.getProducts().add (myProduct);

//Now I can access my product. This will return null because the product does not exist although it was added.
var theProductThatIAddedWas = productCollection.getProducts().findWhere("title", 'Product name');

//And then do this to remove my product
this.productCollection.getProducts().remove(myProduct);
//This product has been detached but I can still remove it and Java will be able to recognize it.
```

This will not work because I have to store the products in a variable first before using them and once I have made changes to the products I have to replace the existing products with the new products. With something like;

```
var products = this.productCollection.getProducts();
//Make changes and then.
this.productCollection.setProducts(products)
```

I think this is very similar in C# and C++ although I have not touched these for a while. I am using java extensively now. I am surprised that I could write; `mainApp.getProductsData().remove(selectedItem)` and then when I access the products again with `mainApp.getProductsData()` the product has been removed. I am only asking here because I don't think I am going to be able to find a documentation or tutorial for this since I don't know what it is called or how it works. Another example;

```
class MainProgram {
    setProduct (product){
        this.product = product;
    }

    getProdut (){
        return this.product;
    }
}

var product = {
    tile: "Product name",
    sku: "SKU",
    qty: "20",
    price: "20.93",
    salePrice: "12.5"
}

MainProgram.setProduct(product);

if (product==MainProgram.getProduct()){
    //Show return true but won't
}
```

Comment: I don't understand your JS code at all. But to answer about Java, and assuming that productsData is a `List`, the remove happens by comparing items in list with the given item using `equals` method (which comes from class `Object`), which can return true even if they refer to different places in memory.

Comment: So if I create an object like `Product product = new Product()` This product will be assign to a particular place in memory. And let's say I have a method that simply takes the object and returns it for example `Product anotherProduct = storeProductInVariableAndThenReturnIt(product)` And if I do; `if (anotherProduct==product){}` This will return true? I could not do something like this in JavaScript

Comment: Notice here how I access the products and then remove an item (that I previous copied from the collection) `mainApp.getProductsData().remove(selectedItem)`. Now it's say I want to find whether the item exists. I could use `mainApp.getProductsData().exists(selectedItem)` And this would work. (Ignore the exists method) Using whatever method is available I will find that the product doesn't anymore. I could not do something like this. This is what my shows.

Comment: You should learn more about how Java collections work. See the [Oracle Java Tutorial's Collections part](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/index.html). You can find the reference documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ Look for package `java.util`.